# How to find the location of control on some upper level control?

Tags: silverlight

How can i find the location of the 'SomeRectangle' ?

This Rectangle is the location and the size that i need to crop from the 'somepicture' that is actually the picture that appear in the background of the main grid.

```
    <Rectangle x:Name="SomeRectangle" Height="50" Width="50" Stroke="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="5" MinHeight="5" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GeneralTransform gt = 
    SomeRectangle.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual as UIElement);
Point offset = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
double controlTop = offset.Y;
double controlLeft = offset.X;
```

[Source: Silverlight Forum](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/12160/39074.aspx)